# Trace transaction with Go client

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, clients

I need to call the RPC method `debug_traceTransaction` but it's not present within the Go client. 
I'd add a method that performs the call to the RPC endpoint but I'm wondering if there's a reason behind..? Too much to transform?
[The Management API Wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction) specifies that you can use `debug.TraceTransaction(txHash common.Hash, logger *vm.LogConfig) (*ExecutionResurt, error)` but that's not in the client's code.

**Update:**
I put here the basic code I'm using to make the call in case someone wants to do the same thing

```
func DebugTransaction(hash string) (string, error) {
    json := `{"id": 1, "method": "debug_traceTransaction", "params": ["` + hash + `", {"disableStack": true, "disableMemory": true, "disableStorage": true}]}`
    log.Println("Request with:", json)
    jsonByte := []byte(json)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", ethereumNodeAddress, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonByte))
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    log.Println("Request info: " + resp.Status + " " + string(body))
    return string(body), err
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transaction tracing is not exposed via [ethclient](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/ethclient/ethclient.go). You must connect over the regular [rpc](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/rpc) and invoke it as a regular call.

The reasoning for that is given [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17341).